# what does it take to get an answer?

Tags: discussion

So far I have posted 4 questions on this site.  The first three questions all received +1.  I interpret this to mean that my questions are acceptable and do not violate any site rules.  But yet *none* of my questions on this site have yet been answered.

I am starting to wonder if I should just stop using this site altogether.  Some coy repositioning of a question might put it within the scope of another stack exchange site where people seem to answer questions.  I simply post here out of courtesy to the stack exchange gods who like to segregate topics into different sites.  But if questions here do not get answered, it becomes hard to justify the time spent framing questions here.

I have been designing software full-time for 6 years.  While I do not in any way claim to be a security expert, I am a pretty good student and have a lot of reference points to frame questions as part of a research process.  Can someone help me understand what, *if anything*, can get an answer to questions posted on this site?

Thank you.

Comment: Right - I warned you what would happen if you didn't learn while on your suspension. I think you may be right that you are not suited for this site. You do realise that your questions were downvoted and migrated **by the community**, right? Us mods support the community, by cleaning up messes etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a rant. If you follow our site guidelines (as you have been told many times) you will be just fine. If not, you will have posts downvoted, closed, and if you keep doing it you will be suspended.

Answer (score 14):

Of your 4 questions:

- 1 was migrated to SU yesterday, not long after it was asked
- 1 was asked 19 hours ago and has just been closed as off topic
- 1 was asked 21 minutes ago - and to be honest, looks very off topic as well

And the one you asked in December has a comment on it from me that you haven't responded to. The +1's you get just mean that an individual liked the question. It doesn't necessarily have any connection to whether the question is on topic here, or anywhere else, for that matter.

Remember, when you ask a question, none of us is paid to answer - we are all volunteers, so make it easy for us to answer:

- Ask questions that are on topic here (re-read the site [help page](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour))
- Write them well, as per our [How to Ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page
- Respond to comments asking for clarity
- and **be patient**

If you follow those guidelines you may find a much better response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21473/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-codemed).

Comment: Your chat link does not work.  See this link: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/cannot-log-into-chat

Comment: What that post describes is a problem with your setup. The links work (they are autogenerated by the system) sorry if you can't access them.

Comment: The key point I made in that chat is: 
CodeMed - first warning. Our site rules include Be Nice
One thing I will do is suspend you if you break that rule

Comment: They were not auto-generated in a way that works in many systems.  By contrast, I am able to chat in stack overflow without any problem, and I am also able to chat in some other stack exchange sites.

Comment: Answer questions, and more people will use this site.  More people with fresh ideas and new perspectives.  People who think outside the box.  Please don't waste energy putting things into boxes.

Comment: Your post on meta.unix doesn't suggest many systems. From your description it looks like you have a non-standard config. SE supports standard configs, as far as I can tell.

Comment: We have tens of thousands of answers. I have provided over 700. You may like "outside the box", but it won't get you answers, and if you break the rules, you will be suspended. You can deal with it or leave. Up to you.

Comment: No need to get angry.

Comment: If you would only put the energy you obviously have into writing good, on-topic questions you'd be fine. I'm not even vaguely angry - this doesn't get me angry :-)

Comment: Clarifying what +1 does and does not mean: Strictly, the only thing a +1 means is that *one person with just 15 site rep or more* decided to push the "up-vote" button on your question. If they're following SE guidelines, this should mean they found the question interesting or useful. But it doesn't technically indicate any judgement upon whether or not it is on-topic for the site. There are numerous questions across SE which are obviously off-topic for the site they're on, or are even just plain not suitable for the SE format, but which have been up-voted 10, 20, or even 100 times!

Comment: Another thing an up-vote doesn't really you is whether or not the voter is even really *qualified* to pass judgement on the quality or suitability of your question. *15 rep can be very trivially earned with absolutely zero experience* on a specific site. Despite having negligible activity or knowledge on the topics, there's over a dozen sites where my own reputation currently sits at 101 for just having created an account! 1 rep is given to all users, and 100 rep is given to users who have an account on another SE site with >=200 rep.

Comment: Aside from the "association bonus", here's a few other fairly trivial ways to earn 15 rep: 1 accepted answer; 3 question up-votes; 1 question up-vote and 1 answer up-vote; 2 answer up-votes (gets you to 20).

Comment: @Iszi what about accepted edits? :-) Also, it is feasible to both upvote (because it is interesting or helpful) and still vote to close (because it is not appropriate on the site for whatever reason).

Comment: @AviD IIRC, accepted edits are only 2 rep apiece, so you'd need 7 (plus your 1 starting point) to pass the 15 rep threshold. Getting a single accepted answer, or a few up-votes on questions/answers is far easier. And yes, it's possible to both VtC and up-vote the same question - further proving the point that an up-vote has zero bearing on whether or not the question is actually appropriate for SE.